# Confluent Schema Registry - Error while forwarding register schema request

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I get the below error on issuing this ->

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"}' http://127.0.0.1:8081/subjects/Kafka-key/versions
```

to my confluent kafka client. Same exception using Java.

Not able to understand what is url `http://192.168.0.112:8081` in the exception!

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"OrderBatch","namespace":"com.acme.avro","fields":[{"name":"groupId","type":"string"},{"name":"batchId","type":"string"},{"name":"countryCode","type":"string"},{"name":"divisionNo","type":"string"},{"name":"storeNo","type":"string"},{"name":"categoryCode","type":"string"},{"name":"groupConstraints","type":{"type":"record","name":"GroupConstraints","fields":[{"name":"maxContainers","type":"int"},{"name":"maxDuration","type":"int"},{"name":"maxLines","type":"int"},{"name":"maxQuantity","type":"int"},{"name":"maxWeight","type":"int"},{"name":"containerVolume","type":"int"},{"name":"containerCapacity","type":"int"},{"name":"splitOrder","type":"boolean"},{"name":"commodityOrdering","type":{"type":"array","items":"string"}},{"name":"tempBandBuckets","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"array","items":"string"}}}]}},{"name":"orders","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"record","name":"orders_record","fields":[{"name":"orderId","type":"int"},{"name":"pickDueDate","type":"string"},{"name":"programType","type":"string"},{"name":"carryBagRequired","type":"boolean"},{"name":"loadNo","type":"int"},{"name":"osn","type":"string"}]}}}]}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Error while forwarding register schema request to the master io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.RestRequestForwardingException: Error while forwarding register schema request to the master
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.RestRequestForwardingException: Error while forwarding register schema request to the master
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.requestForwardingFailedException(Errors.java:94)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:584)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryRequestForwardingException: Unexpected error while forwarding the registering schema request {version=0, id=-1, schema={"type":"record","name":"OrderBatch","namespace":"com.acme.avro","fields":[{"name":"groupId","type":"string"},{"name":"batchId","type":"string"},{"name":"countryCode","type":"string"},{"name":"divisionNo","type":"string"},{"name":"storeNo","type":"string"},{"name":"categoryCode","type":"string"},{"name":"groupConstraints","type":{"type":"record","name":"GroupConstraints","fields":[{"name":"maxContainers","type":"int"},{"name":"maxDuration","type":"int"},{"name":"maxLines","type":"int"},{"name":"maxQuantity","type":"int"},{"name":"maxWeight","type":"int"},{"name":"containerVolume","type":"int"},{"name":"containerCapacity","type":"int"},{"name":"splitOrder","type":"boolean"},{"name":"commodityOrdering","type":{"type":"array","items":"string"}},{"name":"tempBandBuckets","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"array","items":"string"}}}]}},{"name":"orders","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"record","name":"orders_record","fields":[{"name":"orderId","type":"int"},{"name":"pickDueDate","type":"string"},{"name":"programType","type":"string"},{"name":"carryBagRequired","type":"boolean"},{"name":"loadNo","type":"int"},{"name":"osn","type":"string"}]}}}]}} to [http://192.168.0.112:8081]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.forwardRegisterRequestToMaster(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:587)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:433)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:168)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:195)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:252)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:352)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.forwardRegisterRequestToMaster(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:583)
    ... 54 more
; error code: 50003
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:191)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:218)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:307)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:299)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:294)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:100)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:841)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:690)
    at kafka.KafkaProducerTester.main(KafkaProducerTester.java:47)
```

Comment: Are you running mulitple registries? Can you show your property file?

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8081" use proper host-name and port, and try executing command again.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" 
    --data '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"}' 
     http://<schema_registry_host>:<port>/subjects/Kafka-value/versions
```